# RNN backprop-through-time

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation, recurrent-neural-network

I'm investigating RNNs and after read this paper, got the how Backrpop-through-time works on RNNs:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02583.pdf

But I have some confusion with the following implementation (from cs231):

```
 for t in reversed(xrange(T)):
        dh_current = dh[t] + dh_prev
        dx_t, dh_prev, dWx_t, dWh_t, db_t = rnn_step_backward(dh_current, cache[t])
        dx[t] += dx_t
        dh0 = dh_prev
        dWx += dWx_t
        dWh += dWh_t
        db += db_t
```

Why summing up dh[t] and dh_prev gradients, **dh_current = dh[t] + dh_prev** ?

Full source code: https://github.com/williamchan/cs231-assignment3/blob/master/cs231n/rnn_layers.py